# Return string in a for loop (from chars)

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, return

I am trying to create a simple program to use a Ceaser Cipher. My problem at the moment is that I do not know how (or if it is even possible) to return the full string from the for loop.

What I know (I think..)
The return Ciphered ends the for loop because its a return..
If instead of return I put a System.out.print(Ciphered) it prints the entire string (but it's made up of chars, and is not an actual string).

I am wondering how I can return a string that has had all of the 'cipher' implemented. In this case it should be "BCE"

An explanation would be most helpful! Thanks

```
public class crypto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = normalizeText("ABD");
        String encrypted = ceaserCipher(text, 1);

        System.out.println(encrypted);

    }//main

    public static String normalizeText(String text) {

        text = text.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "").toUpperCase(); 
        return text;

    }//normalizeText

    public static String ceaserCipher(String text, int key) {

        for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
        char start = text.charAt(index);
        char cipherChar = (char) (start + key);
        String Ciphered = "";
        Ciphered = Ciphered + cipherChar; 

        return Ciphered;
        }

        return null;
    }//ceaserCipher

}//class
```

Comment: why are you returning inside the loop? also , is toString() not working?

Comment: The code inside the for loop is what 'applies' the cipher change. I don't think you can get variables created in the for loop out of the for loop (right or wrong?). Not sure about the .toString() but I'll play around with that

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I moved `Ciphered` outside the loop otherwise it is created every time in the loop and return outside as otherwise it will return immediately after adding the first character to the string. here, it waits for the loop to finish execution and then return the string
replace this method

```
    public static String ceaserCipher(String text, int key) {
    String Ciphered = "";

    for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
    char start = text.charAt(index);
    char cipherChar = (char) (start + key);
    Ciphered = Ciphered + cipherChar; 

    }

    return Ciphered;
}//ceaserCipher
```

Comment: That was easy! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. By initializing `Ciphered` inside the loop for each character the `Ciphered` String will go back to "". So take the declaration outside the loop.
2. If you return `Ciphered` inside the loop, it will immediately return and won't run the next iteration. So move the return statement outside the loop as well.

Your code should be:

```
public static String ceaserCipher(String text, int key) 
{ 
String Ciphered="";
for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) 
{ 
char start = text.charAt(index);
char cipherChar = (char) (start + key); 
Ciphered = Ciphered + cipherChar;
} 
return Ciphered; 
}//ceaserCipher
```